# How to reset $PATH on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, configuration, path

I had a server restart and since then I am no longer able to run any commands under SSH.

Any command will just return something like: `-bash: ls: command not found`

I realize my $PATH must have been changed somehow, doing `/bin/ls` seems to work fine.

An `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin:/root/bin
```

I would assume Java is the culprit here, but how do I go around resetting my $PATH variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the following command to add /bin, or whichever directory you need, to PATH.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/bin"
```

You can then add that line to .profile or .bashrc (if you use bash) to make sure that directory is included in your path each time you log in.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your `PATH`, it seems that somewhere in your start-up scripts an application tries to add itself to `PATH` but does it incorrectly. The reason for that is that your `PATH` contains the string `$PATH`, which should have expanded to the actual path, but was included literally as the string `$PATH`.

The fact that the Java path follows `$PATH` in your path makes it indeed the main suspect. It might do something like:

```
PATH='$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin'
```

instead of:

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin"
```

Note the difference in quoting.